# jQuery: .text() is delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning jQuery animation functions and wirting a small game where the user has to click a moving div in a set time frame. The game is writtn so that when the time is up, the final score is displayed and a div gives the user the option to "start again" if the user clicks on it.

The problem is with the timer that is displayed when the game starts., the time is accurate but the display of it is off.

For an example hen the page is loaded, the timer is the last thing to display even tho it calleds called first in `$(document).ready()`

Through debugging I have confirmed this as `$("#time-remaining").text((seconds -= 1)  + " seconds");` comes up first in `setInterval()`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exqe9bz4/) that shows the problem

Apart from confirming in debug mode that `$("#time-remaining").text((seconds -= 1)  + " seconds");` is called first before any other visual display, I am out of ideas as to why the display of the timer is lagging behind everything else when its the first thing to be executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your interval won't start instantly, it will delay for 1000 ms.

You could update the text once outside of the interval.

```
...
$("#time-remaining").text(seconds + " seconds");
// Countdown timer
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    $("#time-remaining").text((seconds -= 1)  + " seconds");
    if(seconds <= 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
        GameOver(points);
    }
}, 1000);
...
```